# Huge memory footprint using setStrokeColor in a UIViewRepresentable view

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-graphics

I have spent about one day trying to locate why my app consumes a huge amount of memory. I eventually located thw cause which apparently is not an issue of my code.

Using context.setStrokeColor(...) causes the final memory occupation grows from ~290Mb to 1Gb.

This the code reduced to proof the issue.

```
struct UIKitGraphView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var viewModel: MainViewModel
    var scale: Float

    init(viewModel: MainViewModel, scale: Float, channelShift: Int) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.scale = scale
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyGraphView {
        let view = MyGraphView()
        view.viewModel = viewModel
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ graphView: MyGraphView, context: Context) {
        graphView.scale = CGFloat(scale)
        graphView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    class MyGraphView: UIView {
       var viewModel: MainViewModel?
       var scale: CGFloat = 1

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            let width = bitWidth * scale
            if viewModel?.values.count == 0 {
                return
            }
            
            for channel in 0 ..< numberOfChannels - channelShift {
                let channelPosition: CGFloat = spaceBetweenChannels * CGFloat(channel)
                
                // In the original code the color values changes for each channel
                let myColor = CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)


                // This call causes the memory allocation grows from ~290Mb to 1Gb 
                context.setStrokeColor(myColor)

                let value0 = ((viewModel!.values[0] >> (channel + channelShift)) & 0x01)

                let y = rect.size.height - bottomSpace - channelPosition - bitHeight * (value0 == .zero ? 0 : 1)


                context.move(to: CGPoint(x: leftSpace, y: y))
                context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: leftSpace + width, y: y))

....

                context.strokePath()
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Running the code without the call to setStrokeColor the final memory allocation is about 290Mb, instead calling setStrokeColor the final memory allocations is about 1Gb.

What did I do wrong? Any idea how to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

While trying to find a workaround, I discovered that:

- context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor) *doesn't* increase the memory
- context.setStrokeColor(CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)) increases the memory
- context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.[any color different from black].cgColor) increases the memory

**EDIT 2**

- Previous tests was performed on iPhone 12 (iOS 14.2.1)
- iPhone XR (iOS 14.1) has similar behavior getting to about 667Mb
- iPhone XR (iOS 14.2) gets to about 667Mb
- iPad Pro (10.5'') (iOS 14.0.1) starts at 126Mb and gets up to 455Mb

Then, apparently the problem is related to the device itself instead of the iOS version.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. A graphics context is grayscale to save space, until you force it to rgb color, at which point it triples in size to accommodate color data. Multiply that by the context dimensions and again by the screen resolution and you can get a pretty big increase.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't think that. It makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: I'll give it as an answer, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is dynamic graphics contexts in action.

The graphics context *starts out as grayscale*, as an efficiency measure, to save space. When you set the stroke color to an actual color, the graphics context has to be rewritten to accommodate that color, so it jumps to about three or four times its previous size, because now we have to store more bits for each pixel to express the color.

Now multiply that by the dimensions of the graphics context (which grows exponentially in the sense that there are two dimensions that need to be multiplied together), and multiply it again by the screen resolution of the particular device we're using, and you can imagine that this change in size would be quite noticeable.